# First time trying to change a light fitting - more wires than I have holes for

Tags: electrical, light

Hopefully someone can help me as I'm clueless with electrics. I'm replacing an outdoor light fitting and don't know what to do with the wires. I've included pictures and will explain what I'm looking at

The old light fitting has a terminal box(?) Labelled L, N, L1. Coming from the wall, brown connects to L, grey to N and black to L1 with an earth screwed in place to the back of the fitting.

[image: old fitting]

My new light fitting has the same size terminal box but is labelled L, a symbol (I assume Earth) and N.

[image: new fitting]

I'm in the UK. House was built in the 60s.

Cheers

Comment: L stands for Load (hot wire), not to be messed with

Comment: Any chance the old light has a timer or something in it? It looks like perhaps it does, which would explain a few extra wires. The power should just be three wires, same as wiring a plug.

Comment: No timer that I'm aware of. It has a sensor at the bottom. Could that be being powered by one of the Ls?